# Print text output on console with echo command without printing start and end quotes

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

I m trying to print a figlet "Utility" using batch script but the output also print the leading and trailing quotes. Below is the code:

```
@echo off
echo " _    _ _   _ _ _ _         "
echo "| |  | | | (_) (_) |        "
echo "| |  | | |_ _| |_| |_ _   _ "
echo "| |  | | __| | | | __| | | |"
echo "| |__| | |_| | | | |_| |_| |"
echo " \____/ \__|_|_|_|\__|\__, |"
echo "                       __/ |"
echo "                      |___/ "
pause>nul
```

When I remove quotes it doesn't print maybe due to special characters i.e. space or \. Please guide me if there is a workaround.
Thanks

Comment: You could use a regular expression to escape the poisonous characters, also online [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zL47T2/1)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the VERTICAL LINE character needs to be escaped.

```
echo  _    _ _   _ _ _ _         
echo ^| ^|  ^| ^| ^| (_) (_) ^|        
echo ^| ^|  ^| ^| ^|_ _^| ^|_^| ^|_ _   _ 
echo ^| ^|  ^| ^| __^| ^| ^| ^| __^| ^| ^| ^|
echo ^| ^|__^| ^| ^|_^| ^| ^| ^| ^|_^| ^|_^| ^|
echo  \____/ \__^|_^|_^|_^|\__^|\__, ^|
echo                        __/ ^|
echo                       ^|___/
```